# Cordova Unable to Invoke Custom URL Scheme to Same Application from InAppBrowser

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3

I have an ionic 3 application that has a webview (cordova-inapp-browser) which is opened in an inappbrowser, and this webview's webpage has a link with a custom URL scheme (e.g: myapp1://) which should invoke the application home page back again (so it exits the inapp browser). It works on Android but doesn't work in iOS.

The inappbrowser cordova plugins used are :
https://github.com/ljcljc/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
https://github.com/Onegini/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

and this is the Info.plist file:

[image: Screenshot of the Info.plist file]

do you think i am missing some configuration knowing that the console does not seem to show errors.

[image: Screenshot 1 of Config.xml file]

[image: Screenshot 2 of Config.xml file]

Comment: Can you share the specific call you're making to open the URL?

Comment: @johnborges, 
this.inappbrowser.create(url, '_blank', options)

options={
location:'no',
clearcache:'yes', clearsessioncache:'yes',
toolbar:'no',
zoom:'no'
}

the url is the page containing the link having the custom url scheme.

Comment: Can you resolve this problem? I can't enable URL Scheme on iOS! Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open external apps you have to use `'_system'` instead of `'_blank'`.

Reading again your question, you want to invoque the same app, right?

The problem is, the url schemes don't work like you think if you are in the same app, the app is already open, so using an url scheme won't open it again as it's already open.

If you want to dismiss the InAppBrowser, you can do 2 things:

1. Listen for `loadstart` on the url scheme url
2. Use `handleOpenURL(url)` function to close the InAppBrowser, as that is the function being called when you invoque the url scheme.

Comment: how to use handleOpenURL(url) please????

there is not like this event... 
can you write a small example please???